# adf richtable duplicates column on page refresh

Tags: oracle-adf

I have jsf page opened as a new window in a dialog containing a table with 3 columns, the problem is that when I close the page and reopen it or refresh it, the columns are getting duplicated meaning i have col1,col2,col3,col1,col2,col3 in the reachtable and as soon as i insert a new row it gets back to normal.
my bean is in session scope and the table is defined in jsfxml doc

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4132274/duplicate-adf-table-column-when-refresh-browser : refer this, it might fix your issue

Comment: We had the same issue on ADF 12C and it got fixed with the latest patch(33084721) available on my Oracle Support.